# upload multiple images in page feed using facebook graph api python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can upload single image in feed using graph api and requestsresponse =

```
import requests
page_id ='page id'
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + page_id + "/feed"
data = {"message":"somemessage","link":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Rivadavia_Battleship_LOC_14781u.jpg/133px-Rivadavia_Battleship_LOC_14781u.jpg"}
requests.post(url,self.content)
```

but how to upload multiple images? any lead would be helpful. I tried most of the other resources.

Comment: That is not even a real image upload, you are just posting the image URL as a link. And no, making a post that contains multiple images is not possible via API, this has been discussed a number of times before already.

Comment: so any workaround? i tried creating album and uploaded multiple image. but still all images displaying separately. not in grid view.